# Edge is not running my JavaScript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

My code is working on Chrome, but not on Edge.

When I choose an option, that option should disappear in the other select elements but it's not disappearing/hiding.

**Code:**

```js
function toggleHide(selectElement) {
  //Getting all select elements
  var arraySelects = document.getElementsByClassName('dropdowns');
  //Getting selected index
  var selectedOption = selectElement.selectedIndex;
  //Disabling options at same index in other select elements
  for (var i = 0; i < arraySelects.length; i++) {
    if (arraySelects[i] == selectElement)
      continue; //Passing the selected Select Element

    arraySelects[i].options[selectedOption].hidden = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <form>
    <select onchange="toggleHide(this);" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns1">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose a status...</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>Orange</option>
      <option>Strawberry</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="toggleHide(this);" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns2">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose a status...</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>Strawberry</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="toggleHide(this);" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns3">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose a status...</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>Strawberry</option>
    </select>
    <select onchange="toggleHide(this);" class="dropdowns" id="dropdowns4">
      <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Please Choose a status...</option>
      <option>Apple</option>
      <option>Banana</option>
      <option>orange</option>
      <option>Strawberry</option>
    </select>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: What *specifically* is not working in Edge? Even in Chrome this just kills all the `select` options, so I'm not sure what the intention is here.

Comment: Are there any console errors?

Comment: When I choose an option, that option should disappear in the other selects but it's not,

Comment: developers use developer tools console - F12

Comment: @DarrenSweeney
DOM7011: The code on this page disabled back and forward caching. For more information, see: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=291337

Comment: @AndréDion I'm trying to make an option disappear when it is selected in other options.

Comment: [link](http://angkas.net23.net/pages/trial.php)

I even tried to up it but it's still not working on edge

Comment: ^^ make sure you include the following when posting: expected behavior, actual behavior, any error messages. In the question, not as comments

Comment: @JuanMendes I will remember that tip. Sorry, it's my first time to ask my own question here.

Comment: From my understanding, that's actually an invalid/improper use of the `hidden` attribute. In any case, the error is likely occurring due to `<select>` elements being handled in a special and implementation-specific way. I would suggest using the `disabled` attribute instead, as this is more user-friendly too (ie. "this option could be selected, but not right now" as opposed to "this option doesn't exist at all")

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I think that is the best possible solution I can also use as of now. Thanks o//

Comment: Have you tried `arraySelects[i].options[selectedOption].style.visibility = 'hidden';`?

Comment: @J.Titus It somehow solves the problem but it's still there and I can still select it. Anyway, thanks for answering